# How to know if premium disks are supported for a particular Azure VM type?

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I want to check if premium disk types are supported for certain Azure VM types or not like for example: if Premium Disks are supported for Standard_A4m_v2 VM or not ? If yes, from where can it be checked, is there any URL ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes) and drill down into each individual VM family, at the top it will say if premium storage is supported.

ps. if the family name contains `s` it would support premium storage afaik

Comment: I’m wondering if there’s a programmatic way to find this information?

Comment: I dont know of such an API, a reasonable work around would be to filter vm families with and without the `s` character, but I dont know how reliable that is (I dont know of any exclusions to this rule, but it doesnt mean they dont exist)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689304/how-to-specify-the-filter-fro-the-azure-computer-rest-api and thought there must be some property on which we can filter to find answer to this question but unfortunately couldn't find much details.

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41. But on the link provided by you, I coud not find the required information- whether the particular VM Type supports Premium Storage or not. Can you help in case I am missing something. TIA .

Comment: click on sku family (compute optimized, memory, etc) and over there under individual skus it will say that

Comment: @4c74356b41 seems to be the most reliable way. Proceed towards creating a new VM, under size selection, the features for all the VMs are provided while filtering, there the Disk type is alo mentioned if Premium ones ares supported or not.

Comment: well, it's pretty much the same, but docs page is a lot easier to get to